# How to PHP Explode in MYSQL and return an array?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a string....

```
$string = "This, Cat, Likes, Lasagna";
```

Using MYSQL only, would it be possible to get an array result like

```
"This" "Cat" "Likes" "Lasagna".
```

Basically, exactly like if I was to do

```
$result = explode('/',$string);
```

Just in MYSQL only? I've seen other examples, but they seem to only return the first result. I need all, in an array format.

Ideally, I'd like to avoid creating new MYSQL functions, and just run it as a independent query.

So far, I've got something like...but this doesn't quite work.

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( 'This, Cat, Likes, Lasagna', ',', 1 ) as part1,
 SUBSTRING_INDEX( 'This, Cat, Likes, Lasagna', ',', 2 ) as part2,
 SUBSTRING_INDEX( 'This, Cat, Likes, Lasagna', ',', 3 ) as part3,
 SUBSTRING_INDEX( 'This, Cat, Likes, Lasagna', ',', 4 ) as part4,
 SUBSTRING_INDEX( 'This, Cat, Likes, Lasagna', ',', 5 ) as part5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
SET @field = 'This, Cat, Likes, Lasagna'; -- your field
SELECT
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@field, ',', -5),',',1) as part1,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@field, ',', -4),',',1) as part2,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@field, ',', -3),',',1) as part3,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@field, ',', -2),',',1) as part4,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(@field, ',', -1) as part5;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I ended up coming to a very similar conclusion myself. But, thank you, thank you, thank you for the help.